# convergence of $\int_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need a hint for this one. I must show that $I(r)=\int_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz$ tends to $0$ as $r$ tends to $+\infty$ ($\gamma(t)=re^{it}$,  $0\le t\le \pi$). I tried with $|\int f|\le \int |f|$ but I didn't get anything useful.

Comment: Are you wanting to evaluate the contour integral? If so you will want a semicircle in the upper half plane with a small epsilon semi circle cut out at the origin since 0 is a singularity. The you have the small epsilon circle that will go to $\pi i$ and the outer semicircle will go to 0 (I think maybe this is what you mean by your question?)

Comment: @MathIsHard it is a semicircle indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\int_{\gamma} \frac {e^{iz}} z \, dz| \leq \int_0^{\pi} e^{-r\sin t} \, dt \to 0$ by Dominated Convergence Theorem. If you need a proof that does not use measure theory first prove that the integral from $0$ to $\pi /2$ tends to $0$ using the fact that $\sin t \geq \frac {2t} {\pi}$ for $t$ in $(0,\pi/2)$. For the integral from $\pi /2$ to $\pi$ make the substitution $s=\pi -t$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it :) (I don't know why people voted -1, the last inequality wasn't obvious).